Determining the visual obstruction in line of sight in QGIS
Based on the planning of a wind farm (numbered dots) with a total of seven wind turbines, I would like to determine the area that theoretically lies within the visual axis of the monuments (blue and white symbol).
It should be noted that the field of view is assumed to be 60°. What approach can I take to determine the relevant area of interference behind the monuments?

The blue lines are at the two eastern monuments, from where I look directly at the monument and see the wind farm in the background. The green line does the same but without the wind farm in the direct background, but in the so-called central field of view of 60 degrees (dashed green line), i.e. an area where a wind farm can also have a disturbing effect when looking at the monument due to the moving rotor blades.

How can I determine this area per monument or for all monuments as a whole, so that I can define the negative visual effects of a wind farm on the central field of vision?

What does "visual axis" mean? Why is a 60 degree field of view important? What's the "area of interference"? I think this question needs some clarification.
